# Do Intel Atom CPUs have ME / AMT?

Tags: vulnerability, hardware

I cannot find much clear documentation about that, especially when it specifically comes to ME.

Regarding AMT, as I understood it requires vPro and Atoms (at least usually) don't come with it.

So is it safe to assume that Atoms/the respective chipsets come without ME/AMT?

Comment: [Am I affected by the Intel AMT/ISM/SBT escalation of privilege vulnerability?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/158576/am-i-affected-by-the-intel-amt-ism-sbt-escalation-of-privilege-vulnerability) provides information and links to all necessary information, which also show the [processors supporting vPro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_vPro#vPro_hardware_requirements). And from this can be seen that Atoms are not affected. Thus marked as duplicate.